# How to round off range of Pandas dataframe columns based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I am new to python. Below is my dataframe, I want to round the colums `COLB` to `COLE` to 0 decimal if the columns are greater than 1 if not I want to assign value 1

```
Name   COLB   COLC  COLD  COLE
A       1.82   2.3   5.2   8.2
B       0.2    8     12.3  1.3
```

I am trying below.

```
for x in (df.iloc[:, 1:5]):
    if x>1:
        df = df.round(0)
    else:
        flex_vol_df[col] = 1
```

Below is the error. When I printed just `x`, I only get float columns. Not sure why the below errors pops. Kindly help!
Thank you.

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this if the columns only have non-negative values

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].aggregate(lambda x: x.round().replace(0., 1.))
```

If the columns can have negative values, then use

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].aggregate(lambda x: np.maximum(x, 1.).round())
```

where `np` is numpy

Output

```
   Name COLB    COLC    COLD    COLE
0   A   2.0     2.0     5.0     8.0
1   B   1.0     8.0     12.0    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`clip` to a lower value of 1, `round` and `update` the DataFrame in place.

```
df.update(df.iloc[:,1:].clip(lower=1).round())
```

Output:

```
  Name  COLB  COLC  COLD  COLE
0    A   2.0   2.0   5.0   8.0
1    B   1.0   8.0  12.0   1.0
```